# What happens if I run "repo sync" twice, in parallel?

Tags: android, git, android-source, corruption, repo

I'm new to the "repo" command as a whole so please bear with me. I was wondering what would happen if I ran the "repo sync" command twice, in parallel?

I have huge repositories being automatically synched and at times some of them might end up being synched more than once, in parallel, so I was wondering if that could lead to any conflicts and/or corruption data or if there is a safety mechanism built-in in "repo synch" to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty safe as repo uses git. Which has excellent multi-process behavior.